# Git pull or clone when read-only access

Tags: git, git-pull, git-clone, git-fetch

I am doing a project for someone and I want to place partial work on their end too. I have a bitbucket account and basically have set it that I am admin and they have read-only access.

The first git pull on their end was without issues. However, then I did more work and when I tried to pull it I had to go through hell to make it work. I kept on making me merge, or it was not working because the head was behind origin and a bunch of other things. So, to make it easier, how should I proceed on their end anytime I have new work done? What should I go for, clone or pull?

Comment: could you add some examples of the output? and how are you going about getting updates from "their end" to yours? are you pushing to a remote, then trying to pull or  are you trying to pull directly from their working repo and then merge in the changes and push to a remote?

Comment: The only one doing the work is me. They cannot push (they have read-only access). They only "test" what I have done. So from time to time, when I have something solid I want them to "play" with what is there and get feedback. So, no, they don't push. I only push and therefore there is no need to pull on my end.

Comment: A few thoughts : Look at the git-config on their end particularly automatic merging options. Based on what your are saying it seems like these should be simple-fast forward merges which can be safely done on automatically. If the source code it not too big and git-clone doesn't take an eon, I don't see why you couldn't just re-clone every time. Not the most elegant way to do this, but sometime that isn't particularly important

Comment: I am using Laravel. Would a git clone replace everything and would delete my vendor folder?

Comment: I am not familiar with Laravel, but if the vendor folder is under version control then no, if it is not then you can move it out of the way and then back in to protect it

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you haven't disabled the `autocrlf` and `filemode`? Then it can happen that the files are modified if you pull them and you get after a time some merge conflicts if the files are modified.

If you commit that merged changed to your local git you get a lot of trouble. So normally there should be no changes on the reading site and you can pull so often you want.